I got a error that Application exit (SharedArrayBuffer is not defined) in flutter webview. My project is qt wasm project. How can I solve it?
I have a WebAssembly (WASM) project that I developed using C++ and Qt. I can run this project on a Python server, which is configured with CORS policies and HTTPS. When I run the server, I can see my project without any errors. However, when I use this local address in my Flutter WebView project, I cannot see the project, and I get a SharedArrayBuffer error.
To resolve this error, I have tried several steps, but nothing has changed. I think I need to run the WebView project with CORS policies, but I haven't found a solution for that.
First, I tried the following steps:
I went to the flutter\bin\cache directory and removed a file named flutter_tools.stamp.
I navigated to the flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web directory and opened the chrome.dart file.
I found the line --disable-extensions.
I added --disable-web-security to that line.
Finally, I attempted to run the command flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security". However, despite all these efforts, the problem persists. I still cannot see the project and continue to receive the SharedArrayBuffer error. I believe I need to find a more comprehensive solution to properly manage CORS and security policies.
